# java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem

Tags: scala, ssl, playframework

I'm getting "java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem"

```
   import play.api.libs.ws._

   ws.url("https://bacd.com")
     .withFollowRedirects(true)           
     .get
```

However, it works with all other URLs I've tried. What is the root cause of the exception?

Comment: In general, is the cert for https://bacd.com installed for java? you might want to add cert to java truststore which would live in `jre/lib/security`

Comment: You neither describe which versions of Java and the library you are using nor what *"all other URLs I've tried"* are exactly. According to [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=bacd.com) the server requires SNI and according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=play.api.libs.ws+sni) there seem to be problems regarding SNI support in the library with some versions of the library and some versions of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the Default SSLContext is set to true. 
`ssl-config.default = true` or you can have a look on SSL-Config here https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/WSQuickStart.html
`